# Fixing YARPP plugin FULLTEXT MySQL indexing

Tags: database

I just found out that the Yet Another Related Posts plugin (YARPP) uses FULLTEXT indexes on the wp-posts table, which greatly slows down sites with a large amount of posts.

Can I can just delete the plugin, or do I have to clean out the wp-posts table of those indexes in order to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YARPP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/) doesn't do anything on uninstall.

So you have to uninstall it then go remove the indexes manually from the DB. The index names should be prefixed with `yarpp_`. Very untested SQL follows:

```
SHOW INDEXES ON wp_posts;
DROP INDEX yarpp_title ON wp_posts;
DROP INDEX yarpp_content ON wp_posts;
```

Comment: Do I just need to drop the yarpp_ tables, or are there columsn in wp_posts that I need to drop as well?

Comment: Just the indexes.